# Xubuntu starts normally on google chrome but not on team viewer

Tags: xorg, google-chrome, fglrx, teamviewer, xorg.conf

I have a remote computer with Xubuntu 14.04.05 installed, everything was fine but one day stopped working, I used for minning, it has 6 gpu, all of them were working fine. After that day I ask someone that has access to the computer to restart it, I could see on Team viewer the computer was online I tried to connect but there is only a black screen indicating the log file for Google Chrome, which was also installed, I went to Google Chrome and I can connect it and open the normal Desktop screen but I can start mining... it says doesn´t have GPU installed... Other mining computers I have same installation and configuration on team viewer I can start miners fine, but not on Chrome...

First I would like to know if there is a way to fix that computer remotely... and second if is possible to start miners on google Chrome.

It only has installed Google Chrome, Team Viewer, fglrx-updates and AMD-SDK3.0, apart from the apps that comes with the normal installation.

Thank you

I found out that deleting xorg.conf file I can see the screen on team viewer but looks like the password changes... not sure why...

Comment: Hi Gustavo. It sounds like you've got quite a complex little setup there. I'm not sure most people will understand extactly what the issue is, it may take someone with some specific knowledge. You could tag your question with some more tags to attract the kinds of people who might know. For instance, the 'teamviewer" tag might help you.